# Black space below titlebar on using custom background for listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom titlebar for all my listview activities using the following window_title.xml

**window_title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#323331">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="11dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4dp">   


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:background="#CFECEC"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/list_icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#4AA02C"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstName"
        android:textColor="#4AA02C"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstName"
        android:textColor="#254117"
        android:textSize="12dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a screenshot of the activity.

[image: ScreenShot of Main Activity]

Here you can notice a black space below the titlebar. How can this be removed?

Comment: Just a thought. Maybe adding `android:fadingEdge="none"` to your list view will get rid of it. It'll also get rid of the fading effect but it may work =/

Comment: @Jack nah, It doesn't work. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I can see the black space. Do you mean there is more of a gap below the icon on the left than above it? If so, try reducing the height of the window_title outer LinearLayout (currently 35dp)...`android:layout_height="35dp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `android:paddingTop="4dp"` in your relative layout of My Main.xml is the problem. Try after removing that.

Answer (score 4):

Play with the `padding, paddingTop, paddingRight values in the root linear layout of your window_title.xml. For a title bar this should be set to 0 on all sides.

Also as @Ravi Bhatt points out the mail.xml contains a top padding of 4. Remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `android:paddingBottom`. Maybe it will work.